# Is it OK to set margin-bottom to em value?

Tags: css

I want to set a margin-bottom:1em so that it's relative to whatever the font size is.

W3C just says it can be px, but [this site](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/margin/) shows em as well.

This will be in an email newsletter so I want it to have broad rendering support.

Comment: Yes, for [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Values), you can use any [length unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length), which includes `em` units. Test *everything*.

Comment: Any unit is valid and W3 does show an `em` example (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin), although I would hesitate to use that in an email without testing.

Comment: @showdev, yeah I test everything but wanted to know what was legal b/c I cant' est ALL browsers.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you. For example, I often find it difficult to test older IE versions, because I don't want to install them on my machines. This gets a bit philosophical, but it depends on what you mean by "legal. Not all browsers conform to W3C standards, so [nothing is foolproof](https://www.webbedfeet.uk/news/w3c-complaint-code--does-it-matter). In the end, your decision will be a judgement call that balances desired functionality and accessibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you've read that W3C says you can only use `px`, because that's not true. W3C clearly states in the newest [CSS Snapshot from 2010](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#value-def-margin-width):

> The properties defined in this section refer to the  value > type, which may take one of the following values:
>
> `<length>` Specifies a fixed width.
>   `<percentage>` The percentage is
>   calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing
>   block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as
>   well. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then
>   the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.
>   `auto` See the section on calculating widths and margins for behavior.

This means you can use anything of the [`<length>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-length) type, meaning em, ex, in, cm, mm, pt, pc or px, or you can use a percentage.

[CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths) introduces even more units.

Comment: It's not that W3C said only px, it was "px, cm, etc."